# Searching multiple xml for children in notepad ++

Tags: xml, notepad++

Not very familar with regex, but basically im trying to pull out the fund price from multiple xml files. So basically i want search to return, all the dates and prices for C001 in the files i have open.

```
<fund>
    <fund_code>C001</fund_code>
    <fund_name>Full fund name</fund_name>
    <fund_price_point>
      <price_point_dt>01/01/2012</price_point_dt>
      <fund_price>50.04</fund_price>
    </fund_price_point>
</fund
```

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks

Comment: This largely depends on what you want to do with them once you've found them. The regex to find the correct lines in the XML is: <price_point_dt>([0-9/]*)</price_point_dt>\r?\n\s*<fund_price>([0-9\.]*)</fund_price>

Comment: You don't want to do this with regex. Why not parse the XML properly?

Comment: So each xml has numerous funds on it and i dont compile the file it gets sent to me. Don't know what you mean by why not parse it properly. all i want to do with the data is to be able to pull it into an excel sheet

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in the Find menu to filter the tags:

Find:

```
</?[^>]*.
```

Replace:

empty string

Then copy the result, and paste into a spreadsheet.

**References**

- [How to use Regular Expressions in Notepad++](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)